# Garage door only closes if you hold the button down even with the safety sensors disconnected

Tags: garage-door-opener

Garage door will not close without holding down the wall button. Only the wall button will close it. Neither wireless remotes work. I have disconnected the safety devises and still have the same issue.

Comment: Some units will not work without the safety sensors. If one had failed you would have the same condition as disconnected. Can you provide the brand / model #.

Comment: Does it close at all before coming back up? Or does it immediately reverse? Could just need some lubrication

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after I replaced a CFL light bulb with an LED.  I assumed it was a problem with batteries, but realized the opener would open the door, but not close it.  When I walk out to the garage, the LED light would come on and created interference so I could not close the door (except by using MyQ).  When I got home, the lights were off, so there was no interference and the door opens!  Removed the LED bulb, and no problems!

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen twice, and it was due to the safety sensors being disconnected. Once I reconnected them and adjusted them to face each other, it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I just paid $50 to find out that Liftmaster garage door openers have issues if you place LED bulbs in the opener.

After the tech swapped the bulbs for incandescent, it is working fine.

Also, 1 sensor is green and 1 is amber, and that is normal.   Only adjust the green sensor, if you have issues closing without override- per service tech.

Comment: Correct. Although [Genie does make an LED bulb that minimizes the interference](https://www.amazon.com/Genie-Garage-Door-Opener-Light/dp/B01IHHVZTW)

Answer (score 0):

The sensor at the bottom of the doorway was loose. I tightened it and now the opener works.